# How can I place an icon in alexa card?

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am developing Alexa app and everything working great now. but for a change i want to change few text with icons. For ex: Address heading should be change with a location icon and so on.

```
$message.='Event Name:   '.$ename.'\nLocation:   '.$vname.'\nAddress: '.$fullAddress.'\nWhen:   '.$ondate.''.$time.$cardMessage;

and card will be displayed like this:

$card = '"card": {
              "type": "Standard",
              "title": "Play Audio",
              "text": "'.$message.'",
              "image": {
            "smallImageUrl": "'.$ArtistImage.'"
           }
        }';
```

because it is full text which is shown on app card, I am not sure how to place an icon for it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to provide a full URL in your `$ArtistImage`.